# How to get button value on click in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button I'm using functional component in reactJs and i want to get button value on click, how can i get this?

My Code:-

```js
const Forms = () => {
    const handleClick =(event) =>{
    const getSameValue = event.target.value
    console.log(getSameValue);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
    );
};
```

Thanks for your Efforts!

Comment: Your button doesn't have the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing would mostly work, although you want [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget), not `target` (you'd see the difference if your `button` had a `span` around its text), but your `button` doesn't have any `value` attribute, so its value is `""`. The *value* of an `input` or `button` is accessed via the `value` attribute (and optionally, for some kinds of `input`, `valueAsNumber` or `valueAsDate`). Your button has text content, but no value.

```js
const Forms = () => {
    const handleClick =( event) => {
        const theValue = event.currentTarget.value;
        console.log("the value:", theValue);
        const theText = event.currentTarget.textContent;
        console.log("the text: ", theText);
    };

    return (
        <button value="this is the value" onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Forms />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a "value" attribute on button tag, example:

```
<button value='button value' onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `value` attribute to the button component and either use hooks or state to set the value and access it throughout the function/class.

Adding `value` attribute to the button:

```
<button value="someVal" onClick={handleClick}>Test</button>
```

Create and store button value using hooks

```
const [btn,btnVal] = useState("")
```

handleClick

```
const handleClick =(event) =>{
    const getSameValue = event.currentTarget.value
    btnVal(getSameValue)
  }
```

For class-based components:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  //const [count, setCount] = useState("");
 constructor(){
  super()
  this.state={
    val:""
  }
 }

 handleClick = (event) =>{
  this.setState({val:event.currentTarget.value})
 }

 render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Button value: {this.state.val}</p>
      <button value="abcd" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Further, you could access the button's value directly using the state or hook variable.